# Toubleshooting Unity, Xcode and Server Connection from Device

Tags: c#, xcode, git, connection, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity to build an Xcode project which is then used to build to a device for testing. The other devs can build just fine and we use Source Tree to interact with our Git.

So... for some reason, even though both Unity and Xcode throw no compile errors and successfully build the app (precisely: the Xcode project, then the App) when I launch the App it throws a generic connection error (cannot connect to server, check your internet connection).

We are trying to eliminate the culprit (if there is indeed just one) - but strangely, using the same Unity player settings and Xcode settings (as far as we can tell) - all the other devs can build just fine and do not receive this connection error. The device themselves work fine, and connect through an App built from someone else's machine, but if I build it from my Mac, it does not work.

Possibly relevant info: Unity and Xcode are both pretty fresh installs as I haven't used them before starting at this company. Not sure if Xcode or Unity (or both) are overwriting certain project specifics pulled from our Git?

Edit: this was a versioning issue, and my minor version increase was enough to cause it. Lesson learned: always make sure you are running the exact same version of any shared IDE / Engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I almost forgot about this question... I solved this by uninstalling the latest version of Unity and then installing the version the other developers were using.

I am not sure what version of Unity I was using at the time of writing - good learning: always post the version of the programs in question. But I do remember it was only a minor update in front of the others. Some small bug fix which ended up causing this connection error.

To anyone else experiencing this problem - if you are having trouble troubleshooting builds and only getting errors from your local machine: make 100% sure you are using the exact same versions of XCode and Unity.